# Call refreshtoken WS only once with RX

Tags: swift, xcode, token, rx-swift

On a screen i have multiple WS called with a token, when token is expired, a function called refreshTokens is called :

```
  func postItemImpersonation(parameters: [String: Any]?) -> Observable<(HTTPURLResponse, T)> {
    let absolutePath = Constants.URL.Impersonation.url
    let impersonationHeader: [String: String] = [
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-Api-Key": "xxxxxxx"
    ]
    return self.manager.rx.request(.post, absolutePath, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: impersonationHeader)
        .responseJSON()
        .timeout(RxTimeInterval.seconds(self.timeOutValue), scheduler: scheduler)
        .observeOn(self.scheduler)
        .map({ response -> (HTTPURLResponse, T) in
            if response.response?.statusCode == 500 {
                throw Error_Code_Network.REST_KO_TECHNIQUE_ERROR
            }
            else if response.response?.statusCode == 204 {
                throw Error_Code_Network.REST_NO_CONTENT
            }else if response.response?.statusCode == 401 {
               
                throw TokenError.unauthorized
            }
            
            let object = Mapper<T>().map(JSONObject: response.value)
            if let object = object, let response = response.response {
                return (response, object)
            }
            throw Error_Code_Network.REST_KO_TECHNIQUE_ERROR
        })
        .retryWhen({ errorObservable in
            errorObservable.enumerated().flatMap({ ( index , error ) -> Observable<Void> in
                if let e = error as? TokenError, e == TokenError.unauthorized, index < self.maxRequestRetry {
                    return self.refreshTokens().asObservable()
                        .map({ succeded -> Void in
                            if succeded {
                                return Void()
                            } else {
                                SessionManager.GetInstance().forceDeconnexion.accept(true)
                                throw TokenError.expired
                            }
                        })
                }
                throw error
            })
        })
}
```

}

but when two ws or more are called and token expired, refreshTokens is called several times, i want it to be called only once

how can i do that please ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article detailing the solution to this problem: [RxSwift and Handling Invalid Tokens](https://medium.com/@danielt1263/retrying-a-network-request-despite-having-an-invalid-token-b8b89340d29)

The key is to create a service that tracks the current token value and updates it when necessary.